# SSIS dataflow: SQL Command from Variable, with parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I defined a variable with the text of a parameterized query like this

```
select * from t where col = ?
```

Now, I am using that variable `@[User::sqltext]` in an OLE DB source for a dataflow task.

Problem is I don't see a way to set the parameters as I would have if I had supplied the SQL text in the source directly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A little touch.
Set your variable `@[User::sqltext]` with property `EvaluateAsExpression=true`, and set the following value for the Expression

```
"select * from t where col = '"+@[User::SomeStringParameter]+"'"
```

Handling expressions for variables is much easier with [BIDSHelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/), an addon for Visual Studio. It provides a special editor for managing variable expressions, as shown below.
[image]

This shows sample for similar task - creation of SQL command. Evaluate button allows to check results before it is executed in the package.